# Apply Swap Operation at Most Once to get a Strictly Increasing Sequence

Tags: python, algorithm

I am doing some of these DS&A questions on various sites online for practice and I ran into this one:

> Given an array of non-negative integers numbers, you are allowed to choose any number from this array and swap any two digits in it. If after the swap operation the number contains leading zeros, they can be omitted and not considered. Your task is to check whether it is possible to apply the swap operation at most once, so that the elements of the resulting array are strictly increasing.

For some reason this had me stumped at first so I went to the gym and thought about it for a while. Eventually I came back to it and tried again, this time coming up with a solution. Unfortunately the solution I got is sort of hideous and clunky and I get the feeling this is not a good way to solve this problem. It works with the tests I have tried but I really want to find a better solution for this. I feel like I must be missing some basic thing that improve it.

So I am posting my code here hoping for some feedback on it.

```
def solution(numbers):

    swaps = 0
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
        if numbers[i] >= numbers[i+1]:
            swaps+=1
            index=i
    if swaps > 1:
        return False
    elif not swaps:
        return True

    swappedI = swapToSmallest(numbers[index])
    if (index-1 < 0 or numbers[index-1] < swappedI) and numbers[index+1] > swappedI:
        return True
    swappedIPlus1 = swapToSmallest(numbers[index])
    if (index+1 > len(numbers) or numbers[index+1] < swappedIPlus1) and numbers[index-1] < swappedIPlus1:
        return True

    return False
    

def swapToSmallest(num) -> int:
    num = str(num)
    smallIndex = 0
    smallestRight = num[smallIndex]
    for i in range(1, len(num)):
        if num[i] <= smallestRight:
            smallestRight = num[i]
            smallIndex = i

    largeIndex = -1
    largeLeft = num[largeIndex]
    for i in range(len(num)-2, -1, -1):
        if num[i] >= largeLeft:
            largeLeft = num[i]
            largeIndex = i

    res = ""
    for i, v in enumerate(num):
        if i == largeIndex:
            res+=smallestRight
        elif i == smallIndex:
            res+=largeLeft
        else:
            res+=v


    return int(res)

    

#tests            
numbers = [1, 5, 10, 20]
print(solution(numbers))

numbers = [1, 3, 900, 10]
print(solution(numbers))

numbers = [1000, 10, 100]
print(solution(numbers))

numbers = [1, 2, 10, 7]
print(solution(numbers))

numbers = [1, 3, 3, 3]
print(solution(numbers))

numbers = [1000, 10, 9]
print(solution(numbers))
```

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Start by checking whether the list is strictly increasing except for one element. Then you can test whether there are any swaps you can make to the exceptional element that will put it in between its neighbors.

Comment: Fails input `[222, 214, 333]`.

Comment: @KellyBundy - Posted an answer that handles this input correctly

Comment: @Mox_z Where? The one I see still returns `False`.

Comment: @KellyBundy The answer I posted starting with "After reading some of the input here and making some modifications" I believe returning false is the correct behavior. Which digits could you flip to make the sequence increasing?

Comment: @Mox_z The digits 1 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely far less complicated solutions. For example, this is one I came up with (just taking a shot, I'm sure there's even more optimised solutions):

```py
def flip(i):
    return int(''.join(str(i)[::-1]))


def strict_inc(xs, single_flip_allowed=True):
    for n, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(xs, xs[1:])):
        if a >= b:
            break
    else:
        return True
    # here, n will be the index at which the first problem occurs
    return single_flip_allowed and (
        (
            (n == 0 or xs[n-1] < flip(xs[n]))
            and (n == len(xs) or flip(xs[n]) < xs[n+1])
            and strict_inc(xs[n+1:], False)
        )
        or
        (
            (xs[n] < flip(xs[n+1]))
            and (n+1 == len(xs) or flip(xs[n+1]) < xs[n+2])
            and strict_inc(xs[n+2:], False)
        )
    )
```

(note that this implements your solution, with added flipping, but not the correct one, keep reading)

Although the function calls itself recursively, it never does so more than once, so there's no issues there.

It basically works on the premise that you can only have a single flaw in the original series of positive integers. So, it finds the first flaw, sees if it can be fixed by 'flipping' the first or second of integer in the flaw and it checks that the rest of the sequence in that case is still strictly increasing (without allow further flips).

You were asking for a review of your code, but given that it's clearly far from optimal, that would be quite an undertaking to do comprehensively.

If you do want a review, I'd suggest trying https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since StackOverflow is really more suited to asking for solutions to concrete technical problems.

Turns out (thanks @barmar for pointing out my mistake, and to @kellybundy for pointing out OP's mistake) that a solution that does work isn't that complicated either (again with room for improvement):

```py
def check(xs):
    x = str(xs[1])
    return any(xs[0] < int(f'{x[0:i]}{x[j]}{x[i+1:j]}{x[i]}{x[j+1:]}') < xs[2]
               for i in range(len(x)) for j in range(i+1, len(x)))


def strict_inc(xs, single_flip_allowed=True):
    for n, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(xs, xs[1:])):
        if a >= b:
            break
    else:
        return True
    # here, n will be the index at which the first problem occurs
    return single_flip_allowed and (
        (
            check(xs[n-1:n+2] if n > 0 else [-1] + xs[n:n+2])
            and strict_inc(xs[n+1:], False)
        )
        or
        (
            check(xs[n:n+3] if n < len(xs)-2 else xs[n:n+2] + [int('9'*len(str(xs[n+1])))])
            and strict_inc(xs[n+2:], False)
        )
    )
```

(another edit: this solution actually tries all possible pairings as needed)

Comment: Where do you swap digits in the number?

Comment: Your `flip()` function reverses the digits, it doesn't swap two digits.

Comment: Ah, it actually flips the entire number - I suppose the same would work to iterate over different substitions, the same argument applies though (just so we're clear: you're right, not a full solution)

Comment: That's what threw me - @barmar is of course correct that the problem description isn't implemented, but I just ran their code and assumed that their solution was the intended. But OPs was wrong to begin with...

Comment: Added a solution to the actual problem as well, left the original to avoid comment confusion.

Comment: I wish people would put as much effort into writing better answers, or editing existing ones as they do into pedantry in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

from itertools import permutations
import collections
def solution(numbers):
sorted_nums = sorted(numbers)

```
if sorted_nums == numbers:
    return(True)

i = 0
def try_numbers(num, idx):
    num = list(str(num))
    flag = False
    perms = permutations(num)

    for p in list(perms):
        #get int
        new_num = int(''.join(i for i in p))
    
        #change the numbers array 
        numbers[idx] = new_num
        tmp = sorted(numbers)
        if numbers == tmp and len(collections.Counter(tmp))==len(tmp):
            flag = True
            break
    
        numbers[idx] = int(''.join(i for i in num))
    return flag
    
while i < len(numbers)-1:

    if numbers[i]>= numbers[i+1]:
    
        if try_numbers(numbers[i] , i):
            return(True)
            
        elif try_numbers(numbers[i+1] , i+1):
            return(True)
            
    i+=1

return(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading some of the input here and making some modifications I came up with this solution. Pretty similar to my initial solution but I think it is handling the cases the other was not.

```
def solution(numbers):
    flaw = False
    for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
        if numbers[i] >= numbers[i+1]:
            if flaw:
                return False
            else:
                flaw = True
                flawIndex = i

    if not flaw:
        return True

    a = swap(numbers[flawIndex])
    b = swap(numbers[flawIndex+1]) if flawIndex < len(numbers)-1 else None

    return (
        (
            True if (flawIndex != 0 or a > numbers[flawIndex]) and a < numbers[flawIndex+1] else False
        ) or (
            True if b < numbers[flawIndex] and (flawIndex < len(numbers)-1 or b < numbers[flawIndex+1]) else False
        )
    )

def swap(num):
    sn = str(num)
    l, r = max(sn), min(sn)
    largeIndex = sn.index(l)
    smallIndex = sn.rindex(r)
    res = ""
    for i in range(len(sn)):
        if i==smallIndex:
            res+=sn[largeIndex]
        elif i==largeIndex:
            res+=sn[smallIndex]
        else:
            res+=sn[i]

    return int(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am at beginning of learning Scala, therefore, any  suggestions of best practices are more than welcome.

```
def solution(numbers: Array[Int]) = {
    val swappedNumbers = numbers.map(listOfPermutation(_))
    val res = Array.fill(swappedNumbers.length)(-1)
    for {
      i <- 0 to res.length - 1
    } yield if (i == 0) res(i) = swappedNumbers(i)(i)
    else {
      res(i) = getNextNum(res(i - 1), swappedNumbers(i))
    }
    if (res.filter(_ == -1).size == 0) true else false
  }

  def getListOfDigits(int: Int) = {
    def getDigits(int: Int, acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      if (int % 10 == 0 & int / 10 == 0) acc
      else {
        getDigits(int / 10, int % 10 :: acc)
      }
    }
    if (int > 0) getDigits(int, Nil) else int :: Nil
  }

  def listOfPermutation(int: Int): Array[Int] = {
    val arrOfDigits = getListOfDigits(int).toArray
    if (arrOfDigits.length <= 1) arrOfDigits
    else {
      val res = for {
        i <- (0 to arrOfDigits.length - 2).toArray
        j <- i + 1 to arrOfDigits.length - 1
      } yield {
        val swapped = (arrOfDigits(i), arrOfDigits(j)).swap
        val copyOfDig = arrOfDigits.clone()
        copyOfDig(i) = swapped._1
        copyOfDig(j) = swapped._2
        copyOfDig.mkString.toInt
      }
      res
        .filter(num => num <= int)
        .sortWith(_ < _) :+ arrOfDigits.mkString.toInt
    }
  }
  def getNextNum(num: Int, arrOfNum: Array[Int]): Int = {
    val res = arrOfNum.filter(_ > num)
    if (res.length > 0) res(0) else -1
  }

  println(solution(Array(13, 31, 30))) //false
  println(solution(Array(1, 5, 10, 20))) //true
  println(solution(Array(1, 3, 900, 10))) //true
  println(solution(Array(1000, 500, 400, 300))) //true
```

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way. I hope can help you. I used some functions that I found. I'm new here :)

```
def flip(i):
    flipper = int(''.join(str(i)[::-1]))
    if i == flipper:
        ans = False
    else:
        ans = True
    return (flipper, ans)

def is_asacending(lstt):
res = all(i<j for i,j in zip(lstt, lstt[1:]))
return res

def solution(lstt):
    if is_asacending(lstt)==True:
        return True
    else:
        NewList = []
        ans = []
        for i in lstt:
            CopyList = lstt.copy()
            y = lstt.index(i)
            CopyList[y] = flip(i)[0]
            NewList.append(CopyList)
            if is_asacending(CopyList):
                ans.append(True)
            else:
                ans.append(False)
        if True in ans:
            return True
        else:
            return False

#check with this
print(solution([1,5,10,20]))
print(solution([1,3,900,10]))
print(solution([13,31,30]))
print(solution([222,214,333]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late but this is my doing with 1 def() only

```
def solution(number):
    new_number = number.copy()  # Create a copy of the input list to avoid modifying the original list

    if sorted(number) == number:
        print("True")
    else:
        for i in range(len(number)):  # Iterate over the indices of the list
            element = list(str(number[i])) 
            for j1 in range(len(element)): # Next 2 lines iterate over 2 different index of the number itself with its length
                for j2 in range(j1+1,len(element)):
                    element[j1], element[j2]=element[j2],element[j1] # swap the 2 indexes at the same time
                    swap_element = int(''.join(element))
                    new_number[i] = swap_element
                    if sorted(new_number) == new_number:
                        print(new_number)
                        break
                    else:
                        new_number[i]=number[i] # Re assign the initial value for the index for another coming iterations
                    continue
    return new_number
number = [1, 1915, 1134, 1432] # Test number here
resp = solution(number)
print(resp)
if sorted(resp) == resp:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```